# How can I keep <sup> & <sub> html tags in my coldfusion string but get rid of all other html tags?

Tags: coldfusion

How can I keep `<sup>whatever</sup>` & `<sub>whatever</sub>` html tags in my coldfusion string but get rid of all other html tags?

Comment: maybe change all the <sup> and </sub> in to two unique strings, then take out the tags, and finally return the unique strings back in to tags

Comment: Might also do a search on [JSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoldfusion%5D+jsoup). It is easy to use and is a great tool for parsing and manipulating html strings.

Comment: Keep in mind that DOM parsing like the suggested JSoup only works if the source content is properly built. We made bad experience with this approach, because target sites change and sometimes end up malformed sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are many ways to run regex magic in CF, I still prefer some Java here to walk through content and capture stuff.

```
<!--- string with tags to strip --->
<cfsavecontent variable="stringToStrip">
    <p class="something">
        Hello <sup>World</sup>
    </p>
    <div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid;">foo</div>
        <sub class="example">bar</sub>
    </div>
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- regex to capture all tag occurences --->
<cfset stripRegEx = "<[^>]+>">

<cfset result   = createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuilder").init()>
<cfset matcher  = createObject("java", "java.util.regex.Pattern").compile(stripRegEx).matcher(stringToStrip)>
<cfset last     = 0>

<cfloop condition="matcher.find()">

    <!--- append content before next capture --->
    <cfset result.append(
        stringToStrip.substring(
            last,
            matcher.start()
        )
    )>

    <!--- full tag capture --->
    <cfset capture = matcher.group(
        javaCast("int", 0)
    )>

    <!--- keep only sub/sup tags --->
    <cfif reFindNoCase("</?su[bp]", capture)>
        <cfset result.append(capture)>
    </cfif>

    <!--- continue at last cursor --->
    <cfset last = matcher.end()>
</cfloop>

<!--- append remaining content --->
<cfset result.append(
    stringToStrip.substring(last)
)>

<!--- final result --->
<cfset result = result.toString()>

<cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput>
```

Output is:

```
Hello <sup>World</sup>
foo
<sub class="example">bar</sub>
```

Comment: This might be effective, but @luke's suggestion is simpler.

Comment: @DanBracuk I do not agree. He has to strip all tags anyway. String substitution is error prone (and would not even work if there are attributes in the sub/sup tag).

Comment: Many years later... this is still a great answer! I updated it for <cfscript> and created a UDF here: https://gist.github.com/homestar9/8d5bccb389bd4f8a0fc72c807fdffff7. Here's a demo: https://www.trycf.com/gist/cce7b377b1707b40de8ec12e8d062895/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use a negative lookahead in a regex replace like so:

`stripped_string = reReplaceNoCase(source_string, '<(?!/?su[bp]\b)[^>]+>', '', 'all' );`